# How do I create a dynamic array of images using database in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim img() As array

Dim imgCount = 2

For each row As DataRow In pathDB.Rows

   img(imgCount) = dateDt.Rows.Item(count).Item("img_path")

   imgCount +=1

Next
```

Comment: look up the ReDim statement

Comment: Or better yet, use `Generic.List(of Image)` instead of an array.  Unless, of course, this is assigned homework where you have to use arrays.  In that case carry on.

Comment: Also, your imgCount should start with 0 and not 2...